# OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor When using pip install

Tags: python, pip

I have seen a lot of down-votes when someone have asked this question, but the question is so diverse and unique and so many solutions which are not working
Personally anytime I am trying to use `pip install` I am ending with this error.

This is after running antivirus scan in my computer.

```
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external ,line 973, 
in get_data OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor>"
```

I have spent more than enough time researching.

**None of these have worked:**

1. Uninstalled python and installed it again.
2. Changed the location of the python to another one.
3. Used pip a standalone

I'm on a verge of replacing OS.
Anyone who has a sure way to solve the problem, kindly share.

Comment: On which python version, what OS and which python package are you trying to install?

Comment: What OS and how did you install Python in the first place. What environment are you tying to pip install into? The system site-packages? ~/.local? A virtualenv? Without more information it's impossible to just guess what your problem is.

Comment: Can someone please remove the "Already answered here" box? That Q/A page is a hot mess and should be ganked frankly. All the answers are either just the one guy spamming something about reinstalling python (Hint: Its probably not that) in windows, which frankly most python people arent using, or other guys saying whether it worked for them or not, none of which are useful answers.

Answer (score -1):

Work from a virtual enviroment ,it will solve all the associated errors

Comment: No it doesnt. And you dont explain why you think it does.